# Python: application with submodules - import doesn't work (NameError: name 'time' is not defined)

Tags: python, module, package

Im building a small application. In my main.py I have:

```
from lib.save_decoded_json import saveJsonToFile
# some code
saveJsonToFile("get_info", outStr)
# some code
```

in lib folder I have 2 files:

```
__init__.py
save_decoded_json.py
```

the last one looks like this:

```
import time

def saveJsonToFile(folderName, packerJsonData):
    timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    with open(folderName + "/" + timestr + ".json","w") as file:
        for result in extract_json_objects(packerJsonData):
            file.write(json.dumps(result, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
    print('-------------------')
    print(folderName + ' SAVED')
    print('-------------------')
```

call to saveJsonToFile throws this error:

```
File "lib/save_decoded_json.py", line 2, in saveJsonToFile
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

Why submodule doesn't import time properly"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only importing the function `saveJsonToFile` not the whole script so you never imported time.

However, you can import `time` inside your function. This will work:

```
def saveJsonToFile(folderName, packerJsonData):
    import time
    timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    with open(folderName + "/" + timestr + ".json","w") as file:
        for result in extract_json_objects(packerJsonData):
            file.write(json.dumps(result, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
    print('-------------------')
    print(folderName + ' SAVED')
    print('-------------------')
```

Comment: That's exactly it, seems I had issues with my environment and it was not correctly refreshing my edits. Thanks!